# Nginx which logging object to use - ngx_cycle->log vs event->log?

Tags: nginx, logging

I am trying to understand which logging object should be used in Nginx modules. For e.g. in [this same method](https://github.com/alibaba/tengine/blob/master/modules/ngx_http_upstream_check_module/ngx_http_upstream_check_module.c#L1775-L1798), at some places I see `ngx_cycle->log`, at other places `event->log` or `c->log`. What is the right way to choose this?

With all of them the logs do show up in the log file though.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/4bf4650f2f10f7bbacfe7a33da744f18951d416d/src/core/ngx_log.h) this is the second argument to function `ngx_log_error_core` and its type is `ngx_log_t*`.

I read about the [cycle](https://nginx.org/en/docs/dev/development_guide.html#cycle) but it's still not clear.